# Net::RBLClient parameter

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to pass additional RBL's to Net::RBLClient, sample code:-

```
use Net::RBLClient;
my $rbl = Net::RBLClient->new;
$rbl->lookup('25.23.75.65');
my @listed_by = $rbl->listed_by;
```

Documentation says that parameters can be passed as hash, however one of then parameter(which I'm trying to use) **"lists"** says it takes array reference. Couldn't understand how it exactly passed on this module.

I've a array reference like

```
my $rack = ['bl.spamcop.net', 'sbl.spamhaus.org', 'xbl.spamhaus.org'];
```

Not sure how this reference included in module construct.

Documentation:- [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~ablum/Net-RBLClient-0.5/RBLClient.pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the docs, the `new()` method accepts an optional hash as arguments, so pass in the array reference as the value to the `lists` key.

```
my $rack = ['bl.spamcop.net', 'sbl.spamhaus.org', 'xbl.spamhaus.org'];

my $rbl = Net::RBLClient->new(lists => $rack);

# then, after the object is created, carry on

$rbl->lookup('211.101.236.160');
my @listed_by = $rbl->listed_by;
```

You could also add other parameters in the same way if you needed/wanted to on object instantiation:

```
my $rbl = Net::RBLClient->new(
    lists => $rack,
    max_time => 10,
    timeout => 3,
);
```

...etc. You could also declare the hash up front, and pass the whole shebang in:

```
my %params = (
    lists => [
        $blacklist_1,
        $blacklist_2,
    ],
    max_time => 10,
    timeout => 3,
);

my $rbl = Net::RBLClient->new(%params);
```